# Guacamole on Linux RDP single application

Tags: rdp, guacamole

I'm wondering if there's some documentation (or if there's simply the possibility of) about expose through Guacamole/Rdp a single application in place of the entire desktop environment.

Has anyone tried this possibility?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start and expose a single application via xrdp from guacamole client in at least two ways:

- by using the `initial_program` field in guacamole rdp connection
- by starting the application via the users .xsession file on the server

Note that the approach using .xsession will always start the application when the user is logging in on the server, even without guacamole/rdp
I have never tried using RemoteApp but that may work too.

Comment: Thank you! I think the number one is the way. Do you know if in the first method the remote desktop is "hidden" and unaccessible by the user during the xrdp session (as in Windows remote desktop application) and if when I close the app also the session is close?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with "Remote App"  in windows server.
You can allow specific applications to specific users. They only use the application and when they stop, the session end. They cannot have acces to anything.
All you have to do is to follow instructions to install rdp connection and then, you add a field in connection's options :

`<param name="remote-app">||calc</param>`

`<param naem="remote-app-dir">C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe</param>`

And it should work.

Comment: Thank you, but in my case the rdp server is a Linux server. So there's a manner to do the same also on Linux?

Comment: There is VNC and SSH for linux but RDP is for windows in almost all cases.
On guacamole i didn't see anything on RDP for linux. If it is available, you could do it in the same way as RDP windows following guacamole's manual.

Comment: I know exists an xrdp server but the goal is: is there a manner to do the same as remote app in Windows with vnc or xrdp or something else and guacamole (so I can have an app on a browser)?

Comment: Remote App is window's exclusive application, and there is a difference between vnc and rdp :  vnc = you take control of the active session, RDP = you open a new session on the server .
I think you can't do RPD's stuff with VNC, but you can still ask on the mailing list.
I hope this brought some help to you :)